# Double spacing in received emails while using Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, text-formatting

Using Outlook 2013 for composing an email, I see that the received email has double spaced. The reason that why Outlook generates such HTML message is explained in various websites, such as

[How to Get Rid of Double Spacing in Outlook](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/rid-double-spacing-outlook-74612.html)

[Messages are Double Spaced for the Recipient](http://www.slipstick.com/problems/messages-are-double-spaced/)

I tried to disable spacing in the normal style. Please see the picture

[image]

But the received email still has double space lines. Note that for signature, I used `shift+enter` so it is fine.

[image]

I am searching for a method other than shift+enter for permanently disabling the double-space option.

**UPDATE**

Even if I use "no theme", still the problem exists

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this a solution for you?

> Turn off your stationery. Follow this path: [new email] \ Message tab \ Signature button \ Signatures option \ Personal stationery tab\ Theme \ [choose none].

(quoted from [Microsoft](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/officeversion_other-outlook/outlook-double-spacing-problem/b3120ff6-e78e-4299-b483-aaf1a800516d?page=2))

Comment: NO effect. Please see the updated post